# How to force SSLv3 in pound HTTP Proxy

Tags: ssl, pound

we are handling SSL with a pound 2.3 HTTP(S) proxy. Is there any way to force a client's Browser to use SSLv3? I couldn't find anything in the pound documentation ...

Thanks for your insight!

Cheers,

Andreas.

Comment: Did you try to do a question in the Pound Mailing list?

Comment: [SSLv3 Is Comprehensively Broken](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7568#page-3)

Comment: Thanks for the warning! Pleaae do remember this is a very old question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you've found an answer by now.  But this was approved by a quality third party ethical hacking firm, Qualys WAS and network scanner, and IBM's AppScanner:

```
Ciphers "ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:+EXP:!eNUL:!EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:!EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:!EXP-RC4-MD5:!EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:!EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:!EXP-RC4-MD5"
```

This removes the sslv2 but leaving sslv3 in place. It is however best practice to disable sslv3 where possible.